# moved website: failed to open stream no such file or directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

I have seen different variations of this problem which I have tried to use without any success so i figured it would be best just to ask.

I recently moved my website from my wamp server over to my qnap server. Seams to be working quite well except 3 errors that popped up (did not have them on my local host and havent changed any of the code).

I get the following 3 errors.

```
  Warning: include(/share/HDA_DATA/Web/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /share/HDA_DATA/Web/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/share/HDA_DATA/Web/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/etc/config/php') in /share/HDA_DATA/Web/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(/share/HDA_DATA/Web/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /share/HDA_DATA/Web/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/share/HDA_DATA/Web/application/views/errors/html/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/etc/config/php') in /share/HDA_DATA/Web/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269
```

I seam to understand what is going on that it cannot access the file but can anyone point out what i need to change and where/which file i need to change it. I have not done any changes to my codeigniter file structure (all original setup). If you need code dump just let me know from which file.

Thank you for your help.

Jonas

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions? It may be that your webserver doesnt have execute privledges for the script files you need.

Comment: i have seen others using chmod 775 but their error has been related to permision denied, i tried chmoding my app folder on the server with 775 but it is still giving the same error

Comment: FIRST in application/log folder check your log file there should be more details. if there is nothing there then go to application/config/config.php and enable the logging. SECOND make sure you have the folder 'errors' inside application/views and that it has the folders and files that came with CI 3

Comment: thanks for your answer. Interesting though, i do not have the error folder under my application/views but i dont have it in my original setup under localhost either and it does not throw any error there.

Comment: So i copied the errors folder from the original codeigniter zip and error went away, just strange how it worked on localhost. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)